# What is the most efficient way to assign a set of jobs to a set of workers?

Tags: linear-algebra

*I am writing a job manager code to parallelize a program for my project. And I am brainstorming ways to get the best algorithm to implement the following:*

I have '$N$' workers. All of them are equal and work at an equal speed, say , '$s$' job units/hour.

I have '$n$' jobs each of type $J_1$ , $J_2$, $J_3$....$J_m$, so in total I have ($n$ x $m$)  jobs.

- Jobs of type $J_1$ are of $j_1$ job units each.
- Jobs of type $J_2$ are of $j_2$ job units each.
- Jobs of type $J_3$ are of $j_3$ job units each.
- ..........
- Jobs of type $J_m$ are of $j_m$ job units each.

What is the most efficient way to divide these jobs among the workers to get all the work done in minimum time?

NOTE-

1. Each job in itself has to be done sequentially so one job cannot be
   shared by different workers. This means, even if a job of type $J_4$ equals working 1000,000,000 job units it has to be done by 1 worker only. Each worker, however, can start and work on multiple jobs at the same time (although of course this means each job takes longer to complete than it would if it was standalone).
2. $N$ can be greater or less than or equal to ($n$ x $m$).
3. $N$ >=$n$

---

In the case where, the number of workers is $>=$ number of jobs i.e. $N$ $>=$ $m$ x $n$ the solution is trivial cause now I can give 1 job each to 1 worker.
But what is the best strategy when $N$ $<$ $m$ x $n$ ?

Comment: This sounds NP-hard, though the fact that there's an equal number of jobs of each type may provide some tractable structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case $n = 1$ is just the [multiprocessor scheduling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling), which is known to be NP-hard, though efficient approximation algorithms exist. It's possible that the fact that the same number of jobs exist for each type would provide some ability to do better than naively applying the usual algorithms for $mn$ jobs, but there's no general-case polynomial-time algorithm unless P=NP.

Comment: "Static" Multiprocessor scheduling is exactly what I have to do. From the looks of it, "Flexible Job Shop Scheduling" algorithms might be what I am looking for. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The LPT Algorithm actually matches the first naiive algorithm i was thinking of. (https://naviewritescode.wordpress.com/2017/03/29/lpt-an-algorithm-for-the-makespan-scheduling-problem/) Might be a good algorithm to begin with.